# Is there a way to implement macros (#define) into a C conversion program?

Tags: c

I'm trying to do a simple conversion program from Celsius to kelvin implementing the function #define with macros but I am having trouble because i don't know if I can do it this way.

```
#include <stdio.h>`

#include <stdlib.h>`

#define SUM(C) + (273.15)`

int main()
{
    float C;

    printf("Enter celsius:");
    scanf("%5.5f", &C);

    float X = SUM(%5.5f) + (273.15);

    printf("The conversion equals to %5.5f Kelvin\n", X);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It would be useful to show for some given inputs, what you expect the outputs to be.  It is unclear what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hint 1: don't use macros at your level. Hint 2: using a macro here is pointless, it makes it more complicated than it is.

Comment: I'm expecting to input the value of 5 and getting 278.5 as the result.

Comment: What's wrong with `c + 273.15`?

Comment: `printf(..., &X)` is wrong, it should just be `X`.  `printf` expects the value, not a pointer to the value.  Yes, it is different from `scanf`, and if you think a little about the fact that C parameters are always passed by value, you'll see why it should be different.

Comment: I've already tried  float X = SUM(C) + (273.15); and i get 0.00000 as the result

Answer (score 2):

This what you need :

```
#define TO_KELVIN(celsuis) ((celsuis) + 273.15)
```

Its considered a bad practice to define macros like this please use functions instead.

**Full code :**

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

#define TO_KELVIN(celsuis) ((celsuis) + 273.15)

int main()
{
    float C;
    printf("Enter celsius:");
    scanf("%f", &C);
    float X = TO_KELVIN(C);
    printf("The conversion equals to %5.5f Kelvin\n", X);
    return 0;
}
```

Your also trying to use `scanf("%5.5f", &C);` the *5.5* won't work for `scanf` its just for the `printf` function.

Comment: I still get the value of 273.15, it does not add the value of the float to the sum

Comment: It works! Thank you so much Omarito. Have a nice day!